# Regex to find links in one row

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
http://pastebin.com/XXXXXXXhttp://pastebin.com/XXXXXX\r
```

I need to extract all links in one line which ends with \r. It can contain one link or even five links. I got something like this :

```
(http[s]*:.*)[\\r|h]
```

but it returns whole row as one match,
any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex in `findall`:

```
>>> s='http://pastebin.com/XXXXXXXhttp://pastebin.com/XXXXXX\r'
>>> re.findall(r'https?://.+?(?=https?://|[\r\n]|$)', s)
['http://pastebin.com/XXXXXXX', 'http://pastebin.com/XXXXXX']
```

`(?=http://|[\r\n]|$)` is **positive lookahead** that asserts next position has `http://` or `\r` or `\n` or line end.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fD7kH2/2)

Comment: Please take care of `https` also :)

Comment: Yes it will match both since I am using `https?` (`s` is optional)

Comment: THANK YOU! Helped me the most! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: `(https?:\/\/[^\\r|h]+)`

Comment: expand column Match information, only green text is a match. It returns only two occurences of http://

Comment: You're right. Fixed the answer. The group just needed to expand a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
va = 'http://pastebin.com/XXXXXXXhttp://pastebin.com/XXXXXX\r'
import re
vac = re.findall(r"(?:https?:\/+)([^\r|h]+)",va)
print vac
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this. Try this:

```
mylinks = []
with open('yourfile', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        for link in line.split('http'):
            mylinks.append('http'+link)
```

EDIT: Looks like you just need one string not the whole file. Just run:

```
mylinks = []
for link in mystring.split('http'):
    mylinks.append('http'+link)
```